# Отменить выполнение sortabble в jQuery ui при клике на определенную часть объекта

Tags: jquery-ui

Есть несколько перетаскиваемых объектов. Как сделать чтобы при перетаскивание срабатывало при перетаскивании за синий блок и не перетаскивалось за красный.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.sort-box').sortable()
});
```

```css
.sort-box{
  width: 300px;
}
.sort-item{
  width: 100%;

}
.red{
  height: 20px  ;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.blue{
  height: 20px  ;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-box">
  <li class="sort-item">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort-item">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort-item">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр [handle](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle):

```
$('.sort-box').sortable({
   handle: '.blue'  
})
```

Параметр [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel):

```
$('.sort-box').sortable({
   cancel: '.red'  
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sort-box').sortable({
      handle: '.blue'  
    })
});
```

```css
.sort-box{
  width: 300px;
}
.sort-item{
  width: 100%;

}
.red{
  height: 20px  ;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.blue{
  height: 20px  ;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-box">
  <li class="sort-item">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort-item">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort-item">
    <span class="red"></span>
    <span class="blue"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Отлично, а есть обратное свойство? потому что у меня много блоков, а  отмена срабатывания должна происходить только на одном

Comment: Можно инвертировать селектор: `handle: ':not(.blue)'`, также есть параметр `cancel`